Prove that $\mathrm{Ind}_H^G(W^*)\cong (\mathrm{Ind}_H^GW)^*$

$H$ is the subgroup of $G$, $W$ is a representation of $H$ over the field $k$, prove that $\mathrm{Ind}_H^G(W^*)\cong (\mathrm{Ind}_H^GW)^*$ (as the representation of $G$).

The definition I learned is that $\mathrm{Ind}_H^GW=k[G]\otimes_{k[H]}W, $ where $k[G]$ is viewed as a ($(k[G],k[H]$)-bimodule. $W^*=\mathrm{Hom}_k(W,k)$ is a $k[H]$-module, where $(h\cdot f)(w)=f(h^{-1}w), \forall h\in H, f\in \mathrm{Hom}_k(W,k). $
Therefore, $\mathrm{Ind}_H^G(W^*)=k[G]\otimes_{k[H]}\mathrm{Hom}_k(W,k), $ and $(\mathrm{Ind}_H^GW)^*=\mathrm{Hom}_k(k[G]\otimes_{k[H]}W,k).$
I tried to construct a bilinear map $\varphi:k[G]\times \mathrm{Hom}_k(W,k)\to \mathrm{Hom}_k(k[G]\otimes_{k[H]}W,k)$, but I don't know how to define $\varphi(x,f)$ for $x\in k[G], f\in \mathrm{Hom}_k(W,k)$, because I do not how to deal with the $x \in k[G]$.
Also the map $\mathrm{Hom}_k(k[G]\otimes_{k[H]}W,k) \to k[G]\otimes_{k[H]} \mathrm{Hom}_k(W,k)$ is difficult to define.
Could you please give some hints? Many thanks in advance!

This is not true. In fact, it's possible to construct examples such that $\mathrm{Ind}_H^G(W^*)$ and $(\mathrm{Ind}_H^GW)^*$ don't even have the same dimension as vector spaces. Suppose that $H$ has infinite index in $G$ and $W=1$ is the trivial representation of $H$, then $W^*=1$ is also trivial. It follows that $\mathrm{Ind}_H^G(W)=\mathrm{Ind}_H^G(W^*)$. But because $H$ has infinite index in $G$, this is an infinite-dimensional vector space over $k$. Now a general result of linear algebra says that an infinite-dimensional vector space never has the same dimension as its dual space, so $\mathrm{Ind}_H^G(W^*)$ and $(\mathrm{Ind}_H^GW)^*$ can't even be isomorphic as $k$-vector spaces.

Sorry, I assumed that both $H$ and $G$ are finite groups and $W$ is of finite dimension.  But your answer is good! Thanks a lot. (Maybe  I will ask a new question.  )

@shwsq have you seen this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2983978/348926

I didn't find this post before. Many thanks!
